# Deleting an Ember.Object created within an Ember.View

Tags: ember.js

Following the documentation, I am able to display the `person` object in the `sayHelloView`. Now I am wondering how I can trigger the else condition to see the bindings in action. Is there a way to do delete the `person` using the browser console or am I barking up the wrong tree?

JsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/PhSRx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have an action which sets the view's person to null.

So in your view template you'd have something like:

```
<a href="#" {{action logout}}>Log out</a>
```

When that's clicked, it will trigger the `logout` method for the view and then you can set `this.person` to null:

```
logout: function() {
    this.set("person", null);
}
```

I've forked your fiddle and updated it, also adding in a login action which sets the person so you can toggle between and see the bindings in action: http://jsfiddle.net/rlivsey/atzfx/

Instead of the view handling logging in and out, you might want to delegate that out to a controller.

Here's a fiddle with an example of `App.sessionController` dealing with holding onto the current logged in person, and the view has a binding to the person so the template stays the same even though the architecture has changed - http://jsfiddle.net/rlivsey/QKa3N/

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and jsfiddles. Is there a guideline/pattern on why it is better to delegate to a controller?

Comment: In this situation I'd expect other parts of the app would need to know about the current logged in person as opposed to that information being silo'd in the view.

In general the view handles the display side of things, using data from controllers and in turn informing the controller of actions that have take place by the users interacting with their templates.